# WebService or WebSocket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, websocket

I am trying to build simple two player Game application in ASP.net/C#.  I am not sure is it best to use WebService or WebSocket. I know the basic differences between them, I just need some advice is it better to choose WeSocket or WebService and why?

I am new on both technologies so the great guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say WebSockets because of the low overhead when transmitting data. Someone else might be able to give a more thorough answer though.

Comment: How does your game work? Do you need real time connections? What is the latency expected?

Comment: Websocket works on all platforms and all browsers? I do not mind the latency. I know the basic info

Comment: If you decide on web services, then use WCF, not the legacy ASMX web services.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning WCF, I did some research about it.

Comment: "Websocket works on all platforms and all browsers?" Most modern browsers have native WebSocket support. There are some challenging platforms (IE9 and earlier, Android). Just be sure to use a solution that has good emulation. Here you can learn more about WebSocket emulation (from Kaazing's blog, the company I work for): http://blog.kaazing.com/2011/11/17/the-industrys-best-websocket-emulation-real-time-web-apps-for-all-your-customers-even-if-theyre-on-ie6/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say use [PokeIn](http://pokein.com). It has DesktopClient for desktop applications that you can benefit from WebSocket in order to communicate them and you can also use the same server side for your browser based solutions. It helps you to call methods from client and server in almost real time without dealing with text parsing etc. PokeIn has its own Websocket server.

1 more benefit is when the customer system is suffering from some firewall etc. PokeIn can create the communication over HTTP interface.